# get store level configuration data instead of default

Tags: magento-1, store-view

I want to get string from store level configuration (for each store differntly), but its taking from default

```
CONST SMS_FOR_ORDER_SHIPPED = 'sendsms/sms_templates/order_shipped';
.
.
.
.
.
Mage::getStoreConfig(self::SMS_FOR_ORDER_SHIPPED)
```

i have also tried

```
Mage::getStoreConfig(SMS_FOR_ORDER_SHIPPED, $order_id->getData('store_id'))
```

I also tried

```
Mage::getStoreConfig('sendsms/sms_templates/order_shipped', $order_id->getData('store_id'))
```

But not working

Comment: Also tried :$template = Mage::getStoreConfig('sendsms/sms_templates/order_shipped',Mage::app()->getStore());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved by

```
Mage::getStoreConfig(self::SMS_FOR_ORDER_SHIPPED, Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($order->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId());
```

$order : I got by using event observer `$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();`

What was the problem ?

-I was getting store or website id irrespective of the order related to website or store. I found that it was giving store id / website id as 0 and hence it was taking data from default configuration.

What is the solution ?

-I have to get store or website id on which the order has received and then i have to get the configuration data related to that particular website(id).
so it will get the website id/ store id of the order.

for example : If Magento has received order from website id 2 then basically it will look like

```
Mage::getStoreConfig(self::SMS_FOR_ORDER_SHIPPED, 2);
```

Where `Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($order->getStoreId())->getWebsiteId()`
will give website id on which order has arrived and then it will get configuration  content belong to that website